# Same Boolean logic works in loop but not in List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, boolean-logic

I've been practising a problem on CodeWarriors in which i basically have to do a difference of sets but retain the **repeating** elements which have not been excluded.

Eg: ([1,2,2,2,3] and [1]) should give --> [2,2,2,3]

So I thought of maintaining the duplicate elements in a list and adding them at the end.

Here's my code with List comprehension: [I have removed the excess debug printing commands I had written]

```
def array_diff(a, b):
    duplicate = []
    duplicate = [i for i in a if a.count(i)>1 and (i not in b) and (duplicate.count(i) < a.count(i)-1) ]
    a = set(a)
    b = set(b)
    return list(a.difference(b)) + duplicate
```

For the inputs: `a = [1,2,2,2,3]  ;  b = [1]`

Gives the Output: `[2, 3, 2, 2, 2]`

Correct Output should be: `[2,2,2,3]`

But the same program **without** list comprehension, the program gives right output:

```
def array_diff(a, b):
    print(a)
    duplicate = []
    for i in a:
        if a.count(i) >1 and i not in b and duplicate.count(i) < a.count(i) -1 :
            duplicate.append(i)
    a = set(a)
    b = set(b)
    return list(a.difference(b)) + duplicate
```

For the same inpu, give the output: `[2, 3, 2, 2]`

---

Why does this happen?

Comment: This is subobtimal. Use a collection.Counter to count the elements. Iterate list once and keep those with a count of > 1. Using count() multiple times will scan the whole list multiple times, using counter and one pass you need to touch element of your list exactly twice.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at counter function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first one, you are checking `duplicate.count` inside your list comprehension. When your list comprehension is *finished*, it will be assigned to the `duplicate` variable. Until then, `duplicate` is whatever you assigned to it before, which is an empty list. So `duplicate.count(i)` is always zero.

In the second version, you are appending to `duplicate` as you go, so `duplicate.count(i)` will sometimes be nonzero.